# NuSoap - Nested Array in addComplexType are allowed ?

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I need to receive from client an XML input like this (with 2 or more elements):

```
<list>
  <item>
      <code xsi:type="xsd:string">123</code>
      <product xsi:type="xsd:string">hello</product>
      <level xsi:type="xsd:float">3</level> 
  </item>

  <item>
      <code xsi:type="xsd:string">1234</code>
      <product xsi:type="xsd:string">hello2</product>
      <level xsi:type="xsd:float">4</level> 
  </item>
</list>
```

May I define a complexType like this to describe input parameter for service method (using an array(array(...)?

```
     $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
       'name',
       'complexType',
       'struct',
       'all',
       '',
        array (array (
          'code' => array('name' => 'code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
          'product' => array('name' => 'product', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
          'level' => array('name' => 'level', 'type' => 'xsd:float')
      ))
    );
```

```
    $server->register('updateCode',                    // method name
             array('name' => 'tns:name'),          // input parameters
             array('return' => 'xsd:string'),    // output parameters
             'urn:updateCode',                         // namespace
             'urn:updatecode#updateCode',                   // soapaction
             'rpc',                                    // style
             'encoded'                                // use

    );

    function updateCode($input){
            return count($input);
    }
```

When I use an XML with 2 items, I obtain 2 as response; when I use an XML with only 1 item, I obtain 3 as response (LIKE THE NUMBER OF THE FIELDS OF EACH ITEM),  where I expected 1 as result.

I don't understand why this occurs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Question is a little old, but I was working on some legacy soap services and came across it.

This SO answer will likely help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505720/1666805

Question 1)
You need to declare 2 complex types where the first is the "list":

```
$soap->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'list',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(
        'list' => array(
          'name' => 'list', 'type' => 'tls:item'
        )
     ),
     array(
        array(
            'ref'=>'tns:item',
            'wsdl:arrayType'=>'tns:item[]'
        )
     ),
   'tns:item'
);
```

And the second having the argument "element":

```
$soap->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'item',
    'element',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'code' => array('name' => 'code', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'product' => array('name' => 'product', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'level' => array('name' => 'level', 'type' => 'xsd:float')
    )
);
```

From here, it should be easy enough to register the function using the list type above as input.

Question 2)
I would look at the actual array being passed to the function instead of the count:

```
array(1) {
  'item' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    array(3) {
      'code' =>
      string(3) "123"
      'product' =>
      string(5) "hello"
      'level' =>
      double(3)
    }
    [1] =>
    array(3) {
      'code' =>
      string(4) "1234"
      'product' =>
      string(6) "hello2"
      'level' =>
      double(4)
    }
  }
}
```